# xampp error server certificate does NOT include

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

```
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:01.051901 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:02.175103 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:02.939504 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:02.939504 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:02.939504 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:02.955104 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1024:tid 220] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2452
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:05.856709 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 2452:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:06.886311 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 2452:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:07.151511 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2452:tid 232] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Error log that occurs when trying to start XAMPP.

Comment: Post `XAMPP` console log also.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options that you should try,

1. If you opened `Skype` you have to close and quit from it. Because of It
   gets `port 80`. (So make sure Skype is not running in the background)
2. And if `SQL Server` is installed there you have to stop those services
   from Windows Services.
3. If `MySQL Workbench` is there, you have to do the same.
4. Disable Anti-virus Program.
5. Right click on `XAMPP control panel` and run as administrator.